# Bind ListViewItem's height to the ListView from dataTemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, datatemplate, listviewitem

I have a ListView in my **Windows Store App**, which selects a template through dataTemplateSelector. In the ItemTemplate of ListView, i have an image. I don't want to fix the height and width of the image, i want to allow it to adjust itself with the space available. So the image can be displayed bigger in big screen size.

Following is my ListView XAML:

```
  <ListView Name="MyListView"  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateConverter}"
                              Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=scroll, Converter={StaticResource BottomMarginConverter}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource GVWIdthConverter}, ElementName=scroll}"
                              Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="MyGridView_Tapped">
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
```

I have set *VerticalContentAlignment* to *Stretch*, this stretches my *ListViewItem* to the size of *ListView*, but the problem is when the image inside the Item is bigger, it increases the size of *ListViewItem* larger than *ListView*. I have also tried setting the height of *ListViewItem* in the above code by adding

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyGridView}" />
```

Following is the code of my ItemTemplate, which is being selected through ItemTemplateSelector,

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PhotoTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="PhotoTemplateGrid" Width="400" Margin="2"  Background="LightPink" >

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid  Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding from.photoUrl}" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="70" />

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,10,0,0"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding from.Name}" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderText}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                            IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="{StaticResource StalkerBlueThemeBrush}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding created_Time, Converter={StaticResource TextDateConverter}}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BaselineTextStyle}"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                            IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap"  FontSize="12" />
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"   />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" TextAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="40" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding message}"  Style="{StaticResource BaselineTextStyle}"
                        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="20" Margin="5,0,5,0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding description}" Style="{StaticResource BaselineTextStyle}"
                    TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   />

                <Image Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding picture}" Margin="2"     />

            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Background="White" >
                        <Polygon Points="15,0 0,15 30,15" Stroke="LightGray" Fill="LightGray" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="View all comments" Style="{StaticResource BaselineTextStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource BlueThemeBrush}" />

                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0">

                            <Image Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="25" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/CtBlueSmall.png" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding CtCount}" Foreground="White"   />
                            <Image  Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="25" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/LeBlueSmall.png" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding LeCount}" Foreground="White"   />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Grid at Row Number 1 `<Grid Grid.Row="1" >`, contains the image which makes the height go larger than the ListView. I want to allow this Grid to stretch itself to the size of its parent. But not cross the size of its parent. in other word, i simply want to bind its height to its parent. Please help me out, i am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the Row Definition applied for that image to 'Auto'?
    `<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>`

Comment: yes, that doesn't help.. and besides, i want to give auto to first two rows which have textblocks, then all remaining space to the image and then center align the image in that remaining area. That's why i am using "*" instead of "Auto". But i have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this in my own project by binding the `Height` of the `Grid` in the `DataTemplate` to the `ActualHeight` of the `ListView`. I does not seem to work if the binding is in the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` style as a setter.

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyListView}">
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```